# How to add a scrollbar in JFormDesigner?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jscrollbar

I have created a JFrame and added a JPanel to it.I need to add a scrollbar to the JPanel. How can I do that?Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) or code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks.Can I use JScrollPane when there are more than one component in the JPanel? I tried adding a JScrollPane to the JPanel,but it seems to work only for one component.

Comment: Do it the other way around. Add the JPanel containing your components to the JScrollPane

Comment: In JFormDesigner it doesn't allow to add a JScrollPane to a JFrame before adding a JPanel.

Comment: Without having used JFormDesigner, I see two ways: 1) You edit the generated code manually to do this (will probably break the designer!?) 2) You add the components like this: JFrame -> JPanel -> JScrollPane -> JPanel (which results in additional components just to make JFormDesigner happy)

Comment: The earlier one you suggested seems to work.I added a JScrollPane to the JFrame first then the JPanel.And Now I'm able to add components to it.Thanks a lot for the help.I wasted many hours to work this out.